# If Flash downloads a file, is it cached?

Tags: flash, caching, plugins

Does Flash use the browser cache when plugin content downloads files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash delegates downloads to the hosting browser.  The Netscape Plugin version (npswf32.dll on Windows) uses NPN_GetURLNotify() and NPN_PostURLNotify(), and the ActiveX version (Flash10a.ocx, e.g.) requests a Moniker, indicating it uses URLMON to perform the downloads.

So, Flash uses the Browser's cache in each instance.  I'm not sure about JavaFX or Sliverlight, but I don't see why they'd go to the trouble of implementing their own when all the browsers that matter make it easy for plugins to use the built-in cache system.

This question sounds like it came about because of some other underlying problem that you haven't described.  Why do you want to know?  What are you doing that raised this question?  If you explain that, we may be able to help you solve your actual problem.

Comment: I wanted to split an hour long file into about 1,000 pieces so you could seek around to listen to and re-listen to different portions of the file without downloading the whole thing.

Comment: For that, I'd recommend using one big file & looking into psuedostreaming. A single large file will always be cached and seeking backwards (i.e. to already-downloaded areas) is free. Seeking forward requires a new server request to reset it to that position.